# variables being reset to null after reloaddata in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, variables, reloaddata

Ive been having problems with reloadData on a TableView. I've finally been able to establish that the variable I use to tell reloadData what to reload is resetting to NULL.

I've added the variable in `ClassAppDelegate.h` as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id globalid;
```

and then synthesized in `ClassAppDelegate.m` as follows:

```
@synthesize globalid;
```

I then acces the variable in which ever class and method i need to use it with (in the method):

```
NDSClassAppDelegate *detailControllerAD = [[NDSClassAppDelegate alloc] init];
```

And then use it in this way to obtain the variable in that method:

```
NSLog(@"GlobalID at FetchTweets %@", detailControllerAD.globalid);
```

Why would my variable be resetting on reloadData?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be instantiating an app delegate object - your application is given one at launch as part of the `UIApplicationMain()` function, and it should live the lifetime of your application. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to get the delegate, i.e. `NDSClassAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. Then, anywhere you need to set or read the `globalid` property, set it on this instance of the application delegate.

Instance variables (which properties are usually backed by) vary independently between instances of objects so you can't store a value in one object and then have the same value appear in another.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this
NDSClassAppDelegate *detailControllerAD = [[NDSClassAppDelegate alloc] init];
new instance created of app delegate.

use this

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
to get existing instance of app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use above way to share the data throughout the application . I was also have same requirement in one of my previous application . At two three forum i have read about the sharing the data though out the application . But according to them this is not a good practice to store the data at application level because using app delegate as a model object is non delegate related stuff. So the cleaner approach is to use the singleton class . Create one singleton class to preserve all the variables state. That will be the cleaner approach .